# android recyclerview horizontal and vertical scroll like facebook?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCwjK.png)

I was able to find a simple way to achieve both scrolling behaviors in recycleview

Comment: Please check how to ask a question (as in what is a good question or how should a question be) on SO before posting one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a horizontal Scrollview inside a recyclerview.

Comment: This post should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. Initiate the screen with Scrollview & inside apply list view with some fixed size & after that apply the Horizontal scroll view of  & again apply the  like u have to full fill the total screen .

like below design